# What should I do if the data table cannot be read because the computer crashes?

Tags: sql, distribution, dolphindb

The computer crashed during data collection today, and the data table cannot be read after restarting. What should I do?

```py
select * from loadTable("dfs://xgb", "plate_real_attribute") => <DataCorruption> The file [G:/qdata/dolphindb/CHUNKS/xgb/202109M/plate_real_attribute/plate_id.col] is corrupted. IOErr code 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this a community edition? standalone mode and single-copy, right? If so, it is recommended to use the [dropPartition](https://www.dolphindb.com/help/FunctionsandCommands/CommandsReferences/d/dropPartition.html) function to forcefully delete the partition, and then re-import the data.